# Unity cutoff shader has texture's all channels always 0

Tags: unity-game-engine, graphics, hlsl

I am trying to write a cut off shader which utilizes a `_MainTex` in a `ShadowCaster` pass where I have the pass:

```
Pass {
  Name "ShadowCaster"
  Tags {
    "LightMode"="ShadowCaster"
  }
  Offset 1, 1
  Cull Off

  CGPROGRAM
  #pragma vertex vert
  #pragma fragment frag
  // ...
  #pragma multi_compile_shadowcaster
  // ...

  // structs and variables
  // ...
}
```

The frag shader is like:

```
float4 frag(VertexOutput i, float facing : VFACE) : COLOR {

  // no shadow on the pixel if alpha less than a cutoff
  float4 texcol = tex2D( _MainTex, i.uv1.xy );
  // but it's always = 0, so everything is cutoff
  clip(texcol.a * _Color.a - _Cutoff);
  // it returns 0, which doesn't matter
  SHADOW_CASTER_FRAGMENT(i)
}
```

The `texcol` always has 0 for alpha channel as I can test with `clip(texcol.a - 0.0)` and modify the number. And the value I used in `tex2D` is straightly a copy from previous pass:

```
VertexOutput vert (VertexInput v) {
  VertexOutput o = (VertexOutput)0;
  o.uv1 = v.texcoord1;
  // ...
  TRANSFER_SHADOW_CASTER(o)
  return o;
}
```

And the structs are:

```
struct VertexInput {
  float4 vertex : POSITION;
  float2 texcoord1 : TEXCOORD1;
  float2 texcoord2 : TEXCOORD2;
}

struct VertexOutput {
  V2F_SHADOW_CASTER;
  float2 uv1 : TEXCOORD1;
  float2 uv2 : TEXCOORD2;
  float4 posWorld : TEXCOORD3;
}
```

What is wrong with the texture transformation I used in `tex2D`? Or is it something else? I am sure the texture itself does provide correct alpha value.

---

*Update*. The full shader pass is on gist, there's the relevant part: https://gist.github.com/KHN190/0fd1d2bab899fbe2fcc809c6755b3d74

Comment: Please provide full shader code.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Hi, thank you, I updated the pass on gist. I think it's sufficient now?